# Dealing with (cross-process) exceptions in Android custom content provider

Tags: android, exception, error-handling, android-contentprovider

I have a custom content provider in my Android app that works reasonably well.  I expect other apps to also access my content provider.  I would like some clean way to communicate exceptions and errors, but as far as I can tell the Android content provider framework doesn't provide any way to propagate exceptions across processes.

How should I indicate an exception state to my caller?  Do I have to somehow encode it into my returned data and rely on clients to check for it?  Is there any alternative?  If encoding into the ordinary return data is it, what's the best way?  (I can see a number of alternatives for the `Cursor` returned by a `query` call, but what about the `Uri` returned by `insert`, or the `int` returned by `update` or `delete`?)

Comment: When you tried raising some sort of `RuntimeException` from your `ContentProvider`, what happened?

Comment: Using `ContentProviderClient`, `query` and `insert` both return `null` when the provider throws a `RuntimeException`.  In the logcat I can see a message with tag `JavaBinder`: `*** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)`

Comment: and update returns 0 when any exception is thrown (it seems)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a short list of `RuntimeException` subclasses which, if thrown in the provider, will be re-thrown in a client app.  These include:

- `IllegalStateException`
- `IllegalArgumentException`
- `NullPointerException`
- `SecurityException`
- `BadParcelableException`

A more recent update to the `Parcel.writeException` documentation added

- `UnsupportedOperationException`
- `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Source: [Creating Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html) mentions `IAE` and `NPE`; I guessed that the others would work based on [the Javadoc for `Parcel.writeException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeException%28java.lang.Exception%29).

The client app will only get the detail message, not a stack trace or the cause stack.  For exceptional state which can be encoded into a `String` (the detail message), this is a reasonable choice.

I'm still interested in other solutions, too.

Comment: I ended up using Android's [org.json package](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) to encode data into the detail message of an `IllegalStateException`, and provide an API for clients to translate using reflection into other `Exception` classes.

Comment: Noone knows why ContentProvider only mentions IAE and NPE? Parcel#writeException() doc is from API level 1...