# How to handle SQLiteException in Android activity?

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, android-activity, android-contentprovider

I am looking at how to handle exceptions in Android.

In the `update()` function in the sample code for the Notepad Content Provider, it calls `getWriteableDatabase()`, which can potentially throw an `SQLiteException`.

I notice that the `NoteEditor` `Activity` `saveNote()` function has the following code:

```
// Commit all of our changes to persistent storage. When the update completes
// the content provider will notify the cursor of the change, which will
// cause the UI to be updated.
try {
   getContentResolver().update(mUri, values, null, null);
 } catch (NullPointerException e) {
     Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
 }
```

What happens if an `SQLiteException` occurs?. I want to be able to catch this exception in the `Activity` and display an appropriate message to the user (via a toast or something similar).

I thought I could do by adding an extra catch for `SQLiteException`. However, I read the following info in the Google docs:

> "Remember that the Android system must be able to communicate the Exception across process boundaries. Android can do this for the following exceptions that may be useful in >handling query errors:
>
> **IllegalArgumentException** (You may choose to throw this if your provider receives an >invalid content URI)
>
> **NullPointerException**"

So I am now confused - can I catch the `SQLiteException` or not?

Comment: Is the Notepad example even using a provider in a different process? If not, any exception can be caught directly.

Comment: Probably not, but I still want to find out the answer to this question - suppose I had another service separate from the Notepad that did the update (e.g. to sync my notepad entries with the cloud)?

Comment: Hmm, I am confused now - I just read this "By default, all components of the same application run in the same process and most applications should not change this". So, even if I wrote a Service  it be in the same process so I could just catch the exception? Perhaps this mainly applies if you are opening up a provider to other applications?

Comment: Yes, using a `ContentProvider` from inside your own app is usually a direct connection (unless you set `android:process` in the manifest). If you expose your provider to other apps, or you use other apps' provider (e.g. Android's Contacts or Media provider) then all data transfer has to use IPC and no direct Exception propagation is possible. All data including exception need to be serialized and transported from one to another process. And besides `ContentProvider` it's the same for `Service` with an interface to bind to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever possible, you should catch the Exception in the class or component in which the Exception occurred. Use some sort of broadcast mechanism or return value semantics to report errors across processes.

It's admittedly a tricky situation. Some people say that if an SQLite (or other Exception) occurs in a ContentProvider, the provider should propagate the exception upwards instead of returning null in the Cursor. However, this generally won't work across processes! On the other hand, returning null doesn't give you a lot of information.

A limited set of Exceptions [do traverse process boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12012173), but SQLiteException isn't among them - still they might be useful/appropriate.